# How to group bars in ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to created a paired bar plot, with each pair comparing a preop and a postop score. 3 of the comparisons are from using  procedure A (SDR), and the other 3 are from using procedure B (ITB). I'm looking for a way to categorize these bars with an additional variable (procedure).

Here's my code:

```
newMAS <- read.csv(header=TRUE, "allMASpaired.csv")
#Prevent Time from getting alphabeticalized
newMAS$Paper <- factor(newMAS$Paper, 
levels=unique(as.character(newMAS$Paper)) )
newMAS$Time <- factor(newMAS$Time, levels=unique(as.character(newMAS$Time)) )

library(ggplot2)

pdf(file="allMASplotPAIRED.pdf")

ggplot(data=newMAS, aes(x=Paper, y=MAS, fill=Time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=n), vjust=-1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: could you make a Rep(roducible) Ex(ample). https://www.tidyverse.org/help/
Also what's happening when you try to create your plot? quick glance seems like you got it.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry I'm having a hard time figuring out Repex...I've installed the package and this is all I've been able to do (I have RStudio):

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say there was I've been able to install Repex and get my code into a clipboard, but I can't figure out what to do from there..I don't see a 'render' button...

Comment: Ok what's the error you're getting when you're trying to plot?

Comment: Basically, this code makes a paired barplot comparing preop to postop values, but I'd like to introduce an additional way to categorize, either with a label or more colors, to show that the first 3 column pairs represent one type of surgery, while the last 3 column pairs represent another type of surgery....

Comment: ah! add a column named "surg.type" and code it as SDR or ITB.  You can use the values in variable `paper` as a condition to ifelse
Can you paste head(newMAS) in your question?

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your fast help! I don't know what you want me to paste, the data is:                     Paper Time       MAS Procedure  n
Ailon Preop 3.4 SDR 20
Ailon Postop 2.4 SDR 
D'Aquino Preop 3.2 SDR 54
D'Aquino Postop 0 SDR 
Ingale Preop 3.6 SDR 10
Ingale Postop 2.3 SDR 
Campbell Preop 2.1 ITB          20
Campbell Postop 1.42 ITB 
Kraus Preop 3.8 ITB      13
Kraus Postop 2.1 ITB 
Ward Preop 2.28 ITB      25
Ward Postop 1.43 ITB

Comment: Wow sorry that looked formatted as I was typing it out....is there a better way to send that? This won't seem to let me attach anything

Comment: I obviously have a lot to learn..

Comment: edit your question and paste it there. or if you're allowed to share data, paste it on dropbox and share a link

Comment: Here's the csv file for the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6dvn6pph5vi11x/allMASpaired.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link to your data.
I added a column called `surg.type`. Guessed which papers where SDR and which 
where ITB. Change accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
#some data munging
allMAS %>% # adding a surg.type
  mutate(surg.type = case_when(
         (Paper %in% c("Ailon","D'Aquino","Ingale")) ~ "SDR",
         TRUE ~ "ITB")) ->allMAS
```

Then plotted it, i did facet_wrap on `surg.type`, this groups papers of one type together in one panel and also did scales="free_x" so the x labels are not repeated. try it without it, to see what happens

```
ggplot(allMAS, aes(y=mas,x=paper)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=time),stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +facet_wrap(~surg.type, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! That is awesome. You're super skilled.